# How to restart postgres sorintlab/stolon deployed on kubernetes cluster

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, stolon

I updated some configurations for Postgres  [sorintlab/stolon](https://github.com/sorintlab/stolon) deployed on kubernetes cluster and trying to restart it, I couldn't find a clear instruction for doing it.

Comment: Did you try `stolonctl pgrestart` command? Check [this answer](https://github.com/sorintlab/stolon/issues/88#issuecomment-419488357) for more information.

Comment: @MikolajS. yes I tried this solution, I got the error that pgrestart is unknown (unknown command "pgrestart" for "stolonctl")
stolonctl version v0.16.0